# Undefined Variable - Works

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which updates a date field in my database. (`purchased`).

I'm also using that data in another part which updates a second date field which takes the input date and add's 6 years `$duedate`.  It works just fine but I get the **Undefined Variable** error for the variable `purchased`.

```
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));
```

I have tried defining it using the below, but it stops the second field being updated and does not throw any errors.

```
$duedate = new DateTime($_POST['purchased']);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

$purchased = "";
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

$purchased = null;
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

$purchased = isset($_POST['purchased']) ? $_POST['purchased'] : '';
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

$purchased = !empty($_POST['purchased']) ? $_POST['purchased'] : '';
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));
```

**Code**

```
$barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE barcode=:barcode");
$stmt->execute(array(":barcode"=>$barcode));

$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : null;
    $manufactuer = isset($_POST['manufactuer']) ? $_POST['manufactuer'] : null;
    $model = isset($_POST['model']) ? $_POST['model'] : null;
    $serial = isset($_POST['serial']) ? $_POST['serial'] : null;
    $itemcondition = isset($_POST['itemcondition']) ? $_POST['itemcondition'] : null;
    $locationb = isset($_POST['locationb']) ? $_POST['locationb'] : null;
    $locationr = isset($_POST['locationr']) ? $_POST['locationr'] : null;
    $comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : null;
    $purchased = isset($_POST['purchased']) ? $_POST['purchased'] : null;
    $retired = isset($_POST['retired']) ? $_POST['retired'] : null;
    $stolen = isset($_POST['stolen']) ? $_POST['stolen'] : null;
    $latest = isset($_POST['latest']) ? $_POST['latest'] : null;
    $due = isset($_POST['due']) ? $_POST['due'] : null;

    $sql_part = array();
    $prepare = array();
    if ($category){
        $sql_part[] = 'category = :category';
        $prepare[':category'] = $category;
    }
    if($manufactuer){
        $sql_part[] = 'manufactuer = :manufactuer';
        $prepare[':manufactuer'] = $manufactuer;
    }
    if($model){
        $sql_part[] = 'model = :model';
        $prepare[':model'] = $model;
    }
    if($serial){
        $sql_part[] = 'serial = :serial';
        $prepare[':serial'] = $serial;
    }
    if($itemcondition){
        $sql_part[] = 'itemcondition = :itemcondition';
        $prepare[':itemcondition'] = $itemcondition;
    }
    if($locationb){
        $sql_part[] = 'locationb = :locationb';
        $prepare[':locationb'] = $locationb;
    }
    if($locationr){
        $sql_part[] = 'locationr = :locationr';
        $prepare[':locationr'] = $locationr;
    }
    if($comments){
        $sql_part[] = 'comments = :comments';
        $prepare[':comments'] = $comments;
    }
    if($purchased){
        $sql_part[] = 'purchased = :purchased';
        $prepare[':purchased'] = $purchased;
    }
    if($retired){
        $sql_part[] = 'retired = :retired';
        $prepare[':retired'] = $retired;
    }
    if($stolen){
        $sql_part[] = 'stolen = :stolen';
        $prepare[':stolen'] = $stolen;
    }
    if($latest){
        $sql_part[] = 'latest = :latest';
        $prepare[':latest'] = $latest;
    }
    if($due){
        $sql_part[] = 'due  =:due';
        $prepare[':due'] = $due;
    }

    $prepare[':barcode'] = $barcode;

    if(count($sql_part)){
        $sql = 'UPDATE assets SET ';
        $sql .= implode(', ', $sql_part);
        $sql .= ' WHERE barcode = :barcode';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if($stmt){
            $result = $stmt->execute($prepare);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            header('Location: ./usearch.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

    <input type="hidden" name="due" value="<?php echo $duedate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

The file is 261 lines so I've included the relevant segments and can add full file if needed.

Comment: `$_POST['purchased]` missing a quote here.

Comment: In your "Code" part (the bottom of your question), where is `$purchased` initialized?

Comment: Fred, didn't fix but thanks for pointing that out.  "Brandon". I've added the full mysql section.

Comment: *" It works just fine but I get the Undefined Variable error."* - Err... "which" variable exactly?

Comment: purchased variable

Comment: ok but for which "line"? You have many. If you're using all this code (HTML form included) in the same file, then an `isset()` or `!empty()` against it would be required. If your HTML form contains an input that contains that variable to be echo'd, that will (also) cause an undefined variable notice.

Comment: The error is for this line `$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
`

Comment: @SaucedApples is it possible $_POST['update'] is not set?

Comment: `$purchased = null;
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);` - that `null` could be the culprit. Try doing the same as you did `$purchased = "";` or just remove it. It being `$purchased = null;`

Comment: Everything else updates - Brandon.  If I remove it or change to `= "";` I still get the undefined variable, but it updates the database.  Adding it them removed the error but the database is not updated.

Comment: @apokryfos that didn't work.

Comment: You are using `$purchased` without defining it when `$_POST['update']` is not set (ie: when you first load the form).  The solution posted below should work for you, it defines `$purchased` when `$_POST['update']` is not set.

Comment: again; for which **line** is that variable undefined? You have many of these `$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);` including one at the very bottom of your code, along with other variables for it. I'm suspecting the one above your `<input type="hidden" name="due" value="<?php echo $duedate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">` which is outside conditionals and is throwing it as soon as the page loads.

Comment: ..further to my comment ^ - Comment out each variable one by one until it stops. There isn't much I can add here.

Comment: It says in the question "the below is what I've tried..." then the bold "Code".  Everything above the "Code" are different attempts and the error is on line `$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);` as mentioned in an above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines at the end of your file:

```
$duedate = new DateTime($purchased);
$duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));

    <input type="hidden" name="due" value="<?php echo $duedate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

are throwing that undefined variable notice because it's placed outside conditionals and as soon as the page is loaded.

That's what I make out of all this.

I posted this, since I made a comment much earlier about it.

Therefore, use a conditional statement/ternary operator.

It will do its job as soon as there is a value for it.

Comment: Ok, so how to I get the variable to be used outside of that conditional?

Comment: @SaucedApples again; "conditional statements". A ternary is best also. So, once it's defined and not empty/is set, it will do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit odd in that you seem to be using the page both in cases where you're updating and in cases where you're not.

Try this:

```
<?php
$barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM assets WHERE barcode=:barcode");
$stmt->execute(array(":barcode" => $barcode));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {    
    $purchased = isset($_POST['purchased']) ? $_POST['purchased'] : null;
    $due = isset($_POST['due']) ? $_POST['due'] : null;
    $sql_part = array();
    $prepare = array();
    if ($purchased) {
        $sql_part[] = 'purchased = :purchased';
        $prepare[':purchased'] = $purchased;
    }
    if ($due) {
        $sql_part[] = 'due  =:due';
        $prepare[':due'] = $due;
    }

    $prepare[':barcode'] = $barcode;

    if (count($sql_part)) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE assets SET ';
        $sql .= implode(', ', $sql_part);
        $sql .= ' WHERE barcode = :barcode';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if ($stmt) {
            $result = $stmt->execute($prepare);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            header('Location: ./usearch.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

if (isset($purchased)) {
    $purchasedDate = new DateTime($purchased);
}
if (isset($due)) {
    $duedate = new DateTime($due);
} else {
    $duedate = new DateTime($purchased?:"now");
    $duedate->add(new DateInterval('P6Y'));
}
?>

<input type = "hidden" name = "due" value = "<?php echo $duedate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Comment: I'm very unclear on what you're trying to do. Your original question only mentioned that you're getting an undefined variable error. I've updated it again (trimmed it down a bit too). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I see you edited and most likely in regards to the comment I left the OP up there, being [this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638493/undefined-variable-works#comment64661185_38638493)